# Import a CPP file into python (different folders)

Tags: python

Im working on a project and I want to access and import break.cpp into car.py

my files structure is:

```
->software
--->car.py //the one I'm using

->shared
--->break.cpp  //the one I want to import
```

I don't think I can use file path such as C/username/... because its a project and multiple people using it.

I tried `from shared.car import *` but didn't worked

Please note that I'll take care of the pybind11 part I just want to import that file -> python

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Does break.cpp already generate python binding with Pybind11?

Comment: Yes don't worry about that part all I want to do is to include that file into python, lets imagine they are both .py files